# TeamViewer QuickSupport on Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, crashes, teamviewer, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Currently the TeamViewer QuickSupport v7.0.640 doesn't run on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (N7100). This is not a hardware problem but a problem with various devices running on Android 4.1.1

The problem seems to be a missing library, I get a handled exeption:

```
could not load application module:
Cannot load library:
link_image[1892]:
1936 could not load needed library 'libsurfaceflinger_client.so'
for 'libjniscreenshot23.so'
(load_library[1094]: Library 'libsurfaceflinger_client.so' not found)
```

So I managed to get a [libsurfaceflinger_client.so](http://www.4shared.com/get/9NXhbT75/libsurfaceflinger_client.html) by searching google.
According to this [XDA Post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30335684&postcount=16) i tried to push the library to /system/lib/ and then chmod rw-r--r--

After launching the App I now get a Force Close due to an unhandled exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Class:
com.teamviewer.incomingremotecontrollib.activity.MainActivity in Method:
onCreate()
```

Any ideas? My guess is that the downloaded library is not for Jelly Bean.